# Show hint with required attribute by clicking

Tags: javascript, html, required

For example i have a input:

`<input type="text" id="username" required></input>`

And also i have a `<button onclick="test_click()"></button>`.

```
function test_click(){
    //
    // Here i check user input
    // 
}
```

How can i show error hint after clicking on button if user input is wrong? I need to execute `oninvalid` event, how can i make this?

Thank you.

Comment: try $('#input_id').trigger('invalid'), but I would advise for you trying use jquery.validate plugin.(sorry fo my english)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I would employ hidden dom elements to provide this kind of feedback. Exactly what dom elements to use depend on how you want your error hint to appear.

For instance, you could have a `<span>` or `<img>` positioned directly next to the `<input>` with the content set to display the error hint. Initially, you want to set the style for this element to include `display: none;` so that it will not appear. Then in your `test_click()` function, you can change the style to `display: inline;` or `display: block;`, etc (as appropriate for your chosen element).

If you're using jQuery, it could look something like this:

```
function test_click(){
   if (error_condition)
   {
      $("#errorElementID").css("display","inline");
   }
}
```

If you're not using jQuery, it could look more like this:

```
function test_click(){
   if (error_condition)
   {
      document.GetElementById("errorElementID").style.display = "inline";
   }
}
```